# Pass identity generated ID to the next page in view as query string parameter through controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller, asp.net-identity

I have a controller function, that adds data to the database, I am passing the data to a view which contains the details of the form submitted. I would like to pass the Identity ID generated as query string so if somebody refreshes the page, I have the ID of the details that were added.

I have tried to add it to form post parameters but it does not work

Controller Function
bvm.Booking has Identity Column BookingID that gets generated.

```
 public ActionResult RequestBookingCustomer(BookingViewModel bvm)
{
            _context.Booking.Add(bvm.Booking);              
            _context.Messages.Add(bvm.Messages);
            _context.PetInformation.Add(bvm.Pets);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return View("BookingDetails", bvm);
}
```

Booking Details View has simple Details page. The url on this page is 
www.xxx.com/Booking/RequestBookingCustomer
with no parameters

```
  <div class="profile-services">
            @*Show all the booking details here*@

            <span>Name:@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)</span>
            <br />
            <span>Weight:@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Weight)</span>
            <br />
            <span>Age:@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AgeYears) Years</span>
            <br />
   </div>
```

How do I pass in the ID generated as query string so if someone refreshes the page, it calls RequestBookingCustomer with some ID that I can check so it does add to the database again?

What am I doing wrong and how can this be fixed in MVC controller to view?

Answer (score 0):

you can use  RedirectToAction method and pass BookingId as query string param to it as following:

```
public ActionResult RequestBookingCustomer(BookingViewModel bvm)
{
            _context.Booking.Add(bvm.Booking);              
            _context.Messages.Add(bvm.Messages);
            _context.PetInformation.Add(bvm.Pets);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            // redirect to get booking details action medthod
            return RedirectToAction("BookingDetails", new { BookingId = bvm.BookingId});
}
```

then inside `BookingDetails` get action method load booking data according to this parameter as following:

```
public ActionResult BookingDetails (int BookingId)
{
   // load booking data for this BookingId
   var BookingData =  _context.Booking.Find(BookingId);

   return view(BookingData);
}
```